# Saving "Device Independent Bitmap" attachment

Tags: vba, outlook

How to properly save this kind of attachment (from signed message)? I saved this with .SaveAsFile method, but it is without any extension and no application can open it.

```
Set OutItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)

For Each att In OutItem.Attachments
    att.SaveAsFile "C:\Temp\" & att.DisplayName
Next
```

Comment: What is the value of the Attachment.Type property? Is it olOLE (6)?

Comment: Yes it is olOLE. How to save this kind of attachment?

Comment: Please see the answer below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the olOlE attachments, you would need to open the attachment as an IStorage COM object and extract the data (which can be mangled) from one of the streams inside the storage - you can see the data in [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/) (I am its author): select the message, click IMessage button on the OutlookSpy ribbon, go to the GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on one of the attachments. Select the PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ property, right click, IMAPIProp::OpenProperty, select IID_IStorage. The data cannot be accessed in VBA using the Outlook Object Model

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) is an option (I am also its author), its [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`SaveAsFile` method is smart  enough to extract BMP, EMF, PDF, Excel, etc. file data from the storage. Something like the following (off the top of my head) should do the job:

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  Session.MAPIOBJECT = Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT
  set rMsg = Session.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1))
  For Each att In rMsg.Attachments
    att.SaveAsFile "C:\Temp\" & att.FileName
  Next
```

Answer (score 1):

The [DisplayName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862398(v=office.15).aspx) property of the Attachment class returns a string representing the name, which does not need to be the actual file name, displayed below the icon representing the embedded attachment.

Try to use the [FileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff867615(v=office.15).aspx) property which returns a String representing the file name of the attachment.

Also you may specify the file extension on the code explicitly, for example:

```
For Each att In OutItem.Attachments
 att.SaveAsFile "C:\Temp\" & att.DisplayName & ".docx"
Next
```

Comment: It doesn't matter which extension I'll add, it is unreadable anyway.