# 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' when trying to save an outlook Attachment

Tags: c#, outlook

I have built a small web application to read appointments from outlook calendar and i used `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook`. Now I want to to able to save the attachments which are inside the appointment.

Here is my code so far :

```
foreach (var item in AppointmentItems) {    
    for (int i = 1; i <= item.Attachments.Count; i++) {

        var Attachment = item.Attachments[i];

        string SavePath = Path.Combine(@"D:\SaveTest", Attachment.FileName);

        Attachment.SaveAsFile(SavePath);
    }
}
```

Problem :

> Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException at exactly
>   Attachment.SaveAsFile(SavePath);

I have already looked everywhere, this method should save the attachment to the path but its somehow trying to read a file.

Comment: Does the directory D:\SaveTest\ exist?

Comment: @mmathis yeah i made sure of that first , and now checking if i have writing access

Comment: No Office app (Outlook included) can be used from a service (such as IIS).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the attachment exist, `FileNotFoundExecption` is triggered by a not existing part of your path. You can check if the path exist first:

```
Directory.Exists(@"D:\SaveTest")
```

Then you can check if you have write rights on the directory:

```
Try
{
return System.IO.Directory.GetAccessControl(@"D:\SaveTest")
        .GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount))
        .Cast<System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule>()
        .Where(rule => (System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Write & rule.FileSystemRights) == System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Write)
        .Any(rule => rule.AccessControlType == System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow);
} catch(Exception)
{
  return false;
}
```

Comment: i am pretty sure writing rights are there because i have tried WriteallText and some other writing and deleting methods to check if i have rights to read or write , the thing the attachment is being saved but then directly deleted as i reach the line                            Attachment.SaveAsFile(SavePath);   Edit : typo

Comment: Can you take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072981/saving-device-independent-bitmap-attachment ?

Answer (score 1):

3 things you could try to do:

1. Make sure that the [directory exists](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.exists?view=netframework-4.8)
2. Check if **Attachment.FileName** have valid name and extension
3. Check your [write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410127/c-sharp-test-if-user-has-write-access-to-a-folder)

Answer (score 0):

System.IO.FileNotFoundExecption means it can't find the file you are looking for or the path you are trying to save to in your case.  remove @ and try "D:\foldername\" + attachment.filename. although removing @ should still work I think you need use plus operator. Would help you can post the whole block of code so we can understand what is going on from top to bottom.